# are C# int? and bool?s always boxed when hasvalue = true?

Tags: c#, nullable

[This MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228597(v=VS.80).aspx) seems to indicate that when an `int?` (or any `Nullable<T>`) has a value, it's always boxed (and hence a much less efficient store of data, memory-wise than an `int`).  Is that the case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That page refers to when you are boxing the `Nullable<T>` struct, not the values inside the struct itself.

There is no boxing involved in storing a nullable type until you try boxing the nullable itself:

```
int? a = 42; // no boxing
int? n = null; // no boxing

object nObj = n; // no boxing
object aObj = a; // only now will boxing occur
```

This behavior is no different than when boxing a regular value type (with the exception of handling the null case) so it is really to be expected.

Answer (score 3):

No. The Nullable object is a generic struct, and internally handles the value of T without boxing.

Answer (score 2):

That's not the case. `Nullable<T>` is generic, so it holds the real `int` or `bool`.

The MSDN page is talking about what happens when you box a `Nullable<int>` or `Nullable<bool>`. If you never assign your nullable struct to an `object` variable, you won't incur boxing overhead.